# laravel 4 pattern filter using a wildcard

Tags: api, rest, wildcard, routes, laravel-4

I started using Laravel 3 last week, and then found the new 4 release and I'm trying to convert now.

I have a dozen+ routes that I want to deliver to a specific controller method. i.e., "/api/v1/owners/3/dogs/1 or /api/v1/owners/3" to run "myresourcecontroller@processRequest"

In Laravel 3 I was able to use this: (note * wildcard)

```
Route::any('api/v1/owners*', 'owners@processRequest'); // Process tags resource endpoints
```

I found this example from the documentation but it gives me an error. I get a NotFoundHttpException.

```
//[Pattern Based Filters](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters)
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    //
});
Route::when('admin/*', 'admin');
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong? Is there another way to do this?

I don't want to use the Laravel 4 restful controllers, cause they don't seem to conform to complete restful design. i.e., no verbs in the url.

I have all of my processing written, I just need to be able to route to it.
I need to be able to create new records by POST /api/v1/owners or /api/v1/owners/3/dogs
I cannot use /api/v1/owners/create.

I'm trying to avoid having to write a route for every endpoint, i.e.,

```
Route::any('api/v1/owners/{owner_id}', 'owners@processRequest');
Route::any('api/v1/owners/{owner_id}/dogs/{dog_id}', 'owners@processRequest');
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make use of [resourceful controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) as they're a great asset when building an API. The endpoints you described can be achieved using resource controllers and nested resource controllers.

```php
Route::resource('owners', 'OwnersController');
Route::resource('owners.dogs', 'OwnersDogsController');
```

Would allow you to create an owner with `POST localhost/owners` and create a dog on an owner with `POST localhost/owners/3/dogs`.

You can then wrap these routes in a route group to get the `api/v1` prefix.

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function()
{
    Route::resource('owners', 'OwnersController');
    Route::resource('owners.dogs', 'OwnersDogsController');
});
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Jason. That helps. I changed the first line to array('prefix' => 'api/v1').

Comment: Yeah, I was using PHP 5.4 syntax. :)

Comment: I'm getting this error (MethodNotAllowedHttpException) when I do a POST to /api/v1/owners/1/dogs/2

Comment: Aha, I found the problem. It is proper for it to reject a POST with a subcollection id in the http protocol. I changed this to /api/v1/owners/1/dogs   We will use a PUT with a subcollection id to update a specific dog.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No worries. If this is the correct answer don't forget to mark it as such.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't used Laravel myself, but try `any('api/v1/owners/*',` (note slash before asterisk) as in the example.

Comment: Oh well. Was worth a try :)